# javabean and form submit execution order issue

Tags: javascript, jsp, javabeans, forms

Here's my issue:

I have a html form that after a user fills in all the required fields I need to do two things.

1st. I save the values in a javabean using the jsp:setProperty name="bean" property="*"/
call
2nd. I move to a new page. However the page I move to depends on what the user has submitted in one of the fields.

I currently have the following javascript call on my button to execute the change of page:

$("#entry").submit(function(){
        if(validate()){
            var value = $("#dataSource").val();
            if(value == "Production"){
                window.location="CAPARequestProduction.jsp";
            }else if(value == "Customer/Warranty"){
                window.location="CAPARequestCustWarr.jsp";
            }else{
                alert("INVALID CHOICE: Please choose Production or Customer/Warranty");
            }
        }
    });

THe jsp:setProperty call loops through the values and stores them in the bean.

Here's my issue....when the submit button is pressed, the javascript is called and the field validation occurs and the browser starts to access the new .jsp, however as soon as it has finished and before the new .jsp has loaded the setProperty call executes and after it executes it returns me to my original page.

How can I perform both the javascript call and the setProperty call and still move to the next page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by setting the action value in my form to an intermediate jsp I called redirect. From within redirect I was able to call the jsp:setProperty which set all the values in the bean. The validation was also done in the redirect.jsp using scriplets and the jsp:getProperty function. From there I moved to the corresponding page using the jsp:forward function.

Comment: Please note that this is definitely not the "right" solution.